# Missing Point on ISeries. Is there SeriesCollection in the Avalonia version of LiveChart?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, livecharts, avalonia

I'm using LiveChart in Avalonia and I didn't find a way to remove GAPS/Missing Points on Xaxes, I found on Google some examples of Livechart for WPF that used SeriesCollection but I didn't find SeriesCollection for Avalonia?

Could you tell me what alternative to remove the missing points?

My code is:

```
public ObservableCollection<FinancialPoint> data {get; set;}


Series = new ISeries[]
{
    new CandlesticksSeries<FinancialPoint>
    {            
        Values = data
    }
};
```

My data has missing point, like this:

```
date: 08/01/2024 17:53:00 Open 10,66 High 10,66 Low 10,55 Close 10,55
date: 09/01/2024 10:08:00 Open 10,5 High 10,51 Low 10,31 Close 10,43
```

This is what is showing on chart:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD17K.png)

I Tried se the values of data com double.NaN, like this,

```
data.Add(new FinancialPoint(candleCount, double.NaN, double.NaN, double.NaN, double.NaN))
```

The above solution didn't work.